# How to use htacess to Stop Spam hits originating from specific domains?

Tags: htaccess, spam

I am getting loads of spam/junk hits on my sites, they result in thousands of hits per day which is crippling my server resulting very poor performance on adsense revenue.

Although I am blocking them through IP address way, but this need constant daily updates to cope with them which I am not able to cope with.

I have found that culprits are mostly from specific hosts (or user agents, I don't know exact term)

The PTR record reads as following:

```
*host.colocrossing.com (example: 107-175-65-166-host.colocrossing.com)
*compute-1.amazonaws.com (example: ec2-54-208-232-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com)
*bc.googleusercontent.com (example: 193.73.184.35.bc.googleusercontent.com)
```

Based on my search on internet i tried to use following lines in my htaccess file with no result.

All I want to do is to stop hits originating from above domains.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^amazonaws\.com$ [OR,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^compute-1.amazonaws\.com$ [OR,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^colocrossing\.com$ [OR,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^bc.googleusercontent\.com$ [OR,NC]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^amazonaws\.com$ [OR,NC]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^compute-1.amazonaws\.com$ [OR,NC]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^colocrossing\.com$ [OR,NC]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^bc.googleusercontent\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You will find that blocking whole IP address blocks is the way to go. Try your solution first, however, you will find that domain/sub-domain names are ever changing just like the IP addresses before. Look up the domain, find the AS number, and block that whole IP block. These are not users. BTW- This is likely one of two things. One compromised computers from a web host, or two, permissive hosts of some kind like AWS and Google. Especially where a user can write and execute code to ping sites in a variety of ways.

Comment: Please research the terminology and edit your question.   It isn't clear if you want to match referrers, the host of the IP address, or  the user agent.   You mention all three in your question.   If you need help, give us an example of an IP address you are blocking.  Show how you obtained it from your logs.   Tell how you would turn it into a host name to block.

Comment: Dear All, Thanks for your comments, i want to block hosts such as bc.googleusercontent.com, compute-1.amazonaws.com and colocrossing.com. 

In my opinion, anything hosted on these hosts is not actual user, they are bots or people trying to run scripts.

@closetnoc : Sir, I am doing blocking IP addresses, but they keep on changing IP addresses, Blocking whole range of IP might result in blocking actual users as well. Please correct me if wrong. I agree with second part of your comment "permissive hots of some kind like AWS & google"

Comment: @StephenOstermiller : Sir,Sorry for wrong question, I am novice, I want to stop hosts like AWS, Google & Colocrossing. I am blocking 130.211.144.120 & 130.211.138.158 , i searched on blacklist domain websites and found they belong  to bc.googleusercontent.com They will generating 13000+ hits in 24 hours. Please help

Comment: @MrWhite : Noted Sir, This code is yet not deployed, I am seeking help of Gurus like you to confirm that code is correct so that I can deploy it.

Apologies for mistakes, await help, Regards

Comment: "This code is yet not deployed" - although you did state, "i tried to use following lines in my htaccess file with no result."?! What do you mean by "no result" in this context?

Comment: Do you have access to the server config? `HostnameLookups` must be set to `On` (or `Double`) for the `REMOTE_HOST` server variable to be populated with the resolved domain name, otherwise, this simply contains the IP address (the same as `REMOTE_ADDR`). However, this potentially creates additional load for your server as DNS lookups must now be performed for every request.

Comment: It is perfectly safe to block whole IP blocks of these systems. I studied automated security and engineered self defending systems for stuff like "the grid". Subscriber blocks will not be the same as non-subscriber blocks. When you look up the AS record you will see the registered IP blocks. Only deal with the blocks that you have trouble with and block them. Easy peasy! No worries.

Comment: I am really looking for way out using script to block these ips, they are coming up on daily basis, now client.server.de has also started to come up :-(. I am so fed up with these spammers now, sometimes feel, i should shutdown and sleep peacefully.